# Java , Programmable Macro

Tags: java

Hi guys i am currently on the search on how to make a macro for my personal project.

its like when i press a button in the program and i set the button for example like pressing enter or pressing any binded key's when i press the GUI button in the program it will execute the code and will try and perform or try to copy the command that is like pressing the binded key on the keyboard .

any helm with making this in java or hints will really be a great help in making it , idk on where to start with the code or what it is called

Answer (score 1):

The class [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) will be useful for this.

You can use it to generate GUI input events programmatically, like keyboard and mouse input.

Comment: hi thank you for the comment ill look into it tomorrow morning its already 2:20 am here but thanks again!